# Requesting email for facebook login always ask for permission like an endless loop

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I've implement a facebook login with special permission to get the user email. It does work but the problem is that it also creates an endless loop of calling the permission and I don't know what to do anymore. Here's my code:

```
public void loginWithFacebook(View view) {

            Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

                // callback when session changes state
                @Override
                public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                                 Exception exception) {
                    if (session.isOpened()) {
                        try {
                            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("email"));
                            session.requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        // make request to the /me API
                        Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session,
                                new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                                    // callback after Graph API response with user
                                    // object
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                                        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                                        }
                                        if (user != null) {
                                            try {
                                                if (Utils.isValidEmail(user.asMap().get("email").toString())) {
                                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),user.asMap().get("email").toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                } else {
                                                    //SHOW TOAST NO EMAIL
                                                }
                                            }catch (Exception e){}
                                        }
                                    }

                                });
                        Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
                    }
                }
            });

    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

What happen is that it keeps on saying that you have already authorized the app multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statusCallback will continue to be called for any subsequent changes to the session state (so when you get email permissions, it will be called again), which is why you're going into an infinite loop. I would recommend checking if you already have the email permission before requesting it further:

```
try {
    if (!session.getPermissions().contains("email")) {
        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("email"));
        session.requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: At last! Thank you sir. Well I don't know why I get a vote for close since someone think this problem is too broad but actually this is the only thing I'm looking for. Thanks again! :)